# Gstreamer: why can't I send data over UDP on localhost?

Tags: c++, udp, gstreamer

I'm trying to test udp streaming on localhost but it's not showing anything:

**videotestsrc (or audiotestsrc) -> udpsink (port: 5078, host: 127.0.0.1)**

Here is the code:

```
console_out_inf("TESTING", "Starting work with test elements");
gint port = 5078;
// TEST PIPELINE OUT
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(GSD->pipetest_out), GSD->testsrc, GSD->udpsink, NULL);
gchar* host = "127.0.0.1";
g_object_set(GSD->udpsink, "port", port, NULL);
g_object_set(GSD->udpsink, "host", host, NULL);
if (!gst_element_link(GSD->testsrc, GSD->udpsink))
    console_out_bad("STREAMING", "Error linking test udp elements -- SEND");
else
    console_out_yes("STREAMING", "Correctly linked test udp elements -- SEND");

// TEST PIPELINE IN
gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(GSD->pipetest_in), GSD->udpsrc, GSD->autovideosink, NULL);

gst_element_set_state(GSD->udpsrc, GST_STATE_NULL);
g_object_set(GSD->udpsrc, "port", port, NULL);

if (!gst_element_link(GSD->udpsrc, GSD->autovideosink))
    console_out_bad("STREAMING", "Error linking test udp elements -- RECEIVE");
else
    console_out_yes("STREAMING", "Correctly linked test udp elements -- RECEIVE");
// PLAY TEST PIPELINE OUT
GstStateChangeReturn ret1;
ret1 = gst_element_set_state(GSD->pipetest_out, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
if (ret1 == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    console_out_bad("TESTING", "Failed playing pipetest out");
else
    console_out_yes("TESTING", "Correctly played pipetest out");

// PLAY TEST PIPELINE IN
GstStateChangeReturn ret2;
ret2 = gst_element_set_state(GSD->pipetest_in, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
if (ret2 == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    console_out_bad("TESTING", "Failed playing pipetest in");
else
    console_out_yes("TESTING", "Correctly played pipetest in");

// PRINT PIPELINES
GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE(GST_BIN(GSD->pipetest_out), GST_DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL, "pipetest_out");
GST_DEBUG_BIN_TO_DOT_FILE(GST_BIN(GSD->pipetest_in), GST_DEBUG_GRAPH_SHOW_ALL, "pipetest_in");
```

This is "my own console output":

**EDIT**: not relevant anymore! Everything is instanciated fine, the pipeline was built correctly, yet with

*PIPELINE OUT*: videotestsrc --> udpsink (host:127.0.0.1, port: 5078)

*PIPELINE IN*: udpsrc (port: 5078) --> autovideosink

The autovideosink does not display anything!
By checking netstat -a, no connection on such port is showed.

**Additional INFO:**

1. The graph generated with "gstreamer debugging" contains of course only the video/audio testsrc element connected to udpsink.
2. The first time I run that code, the "Windows Firewall Window" appeared, so I guess something is being sent/received.
3. This is inside a Visual Studio 2013/Qt5 Add-In Project, but that should not be an issue

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This code seems fine but it doesn't relate to the console output you posted.

Try testing your pipeline piece by piece with the command line gst-launch:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v videotestsrc ! udpsink host="127.0.01"
```

connected to a fakesink first and then swapping in the udp sink, once you have it working in the command line mirror the command in code.

try it with host="localhost" or host="192.168.0.1" i can't remember but i think udpsink might have trouble sending to the loopback

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't relate to the output I posted? the first line are just meant to show that the elements are correctly initialized (through gst_element_factory_make(...)

Comment: I just mean without seeing all the relevant code it's difficult to ascertain it's correctness. You may have unwittingly destroyed the elements after creation for example.

Comment: You were right! I was using udpsink in another pipeline. That's why I could not build the pipetest_out with that element inside of it. Yet, now the second half of my question remains: I am sending udp packets on localhost and it's supposed to show the video incoming from pipetest_out, but it's not doing it. Please note that I edited the question and the description. Thx @thesombrerokid

Comment: I've never tried this but i'm guessing it wont work for several reasons:
1.) udp packets are not guaranteed to be delivered and 
2.) are not guaranteed to be delivered in order.
3.)You would need to time the pipelines to run at the same time to avoid missing packets.

It might potentially work if you decode the video to raw frames before sending it, meaning the data doesn't need to arrive in order etc. Ofc there will be a lot more data if you do that

EDIT: actually, that last part is not true, testsrc is already in raw frames.